# What is wrong with this code? I'm trying to insert this file

Tags: python

I am trying to insert a file and I keep getting a syntax error on the line `line = infile.redline()`

```
def main():
  # Declare variables
  line = ''
  counter = 0

  # Prompt for file name
  fileName = input('Enter the name of the file: ')

  # Open the specified file for reading
  infile = open('test.txt', 'r')

  # Priming read
  line = infile.redline()
  counter = 1

  # Read in and display first five lines
  while line != '' and counter <= 5:
  # Strip '\n'
    line = line.rtrip('\n')
    print(line)
    1ine = infile.readline()
    # Update counter when line is read
    counter +=1  

# Close file
infile.close()

# Call the main function.
     main()
```

Answer (score 1):

`rtrip` should be `rstrip`. `redline` should be `readline`. `infile.close()` should be indented, and `main()` should not be.

However, the most serious problem is here:

```
1ine = infile.readline()
```

That first character is a one, not an L.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the standard libraries can make your life much simpler!

```
from itertools import islice

def main():
    fname = input('Enter the name of the file: ')

    with open(fname) as inf:
        for line in islice(inf, 5):    # get the first 5 lines
            print(line.rstrip())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not `redline` but `readline`:

```
line = infile.redline()
```